# GIT error: HTTP 999 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 999 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly 999

Tags: git, http-error, bonobo

When trying to push to a git repository, always received a 999 error.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of seeking found the solution and want to share it if anybody else comes with this problem.

The solution is that git is not happy with files larger than 1Mb. To change this, to go to the .git folder and edit the config file and add the size constrains:

```
[http]
postBuffer = 2048M
maxRequestBuffer = 1024M
[ssh]
postBuffer = 2048M
maxRequestBuffer = 1024M
[pack]
windowMemory = 256m
packSizeLimit = 256m
```

Comment: Which file to edit? This article explains: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved